# How can I choose the filenames when publishing from Ligthroom?

Tags: lightroom-3

I currently use a publish to hard disk publish service for exporting photos ready for upload to my website. I'd like to be able to be able to choose the filenames on the output files to be something different to the filename as it came off the camera. I'd prefer to keep the original file's name "as-is", but is there any way I can influence the filename to be used when the file is published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit edit settings on your publish service, there should be a "File Naming" section (3rd down for me) where you can choose to rename the images as they are published. The drop down has a bunch of caned options, plus an editor that gets you access to a TON of variables from the catalog that you can build your own custom name up with.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, check ""File Naming" in the publishing options. As an example, I use a "What - Where - When" naming convention automatically generated by Lightroom. It looks like this for example:

```
  St. Patrick's Day - Albany, NY - 09, Mar - 01.jpg
  St. Patrick's Day - Albany, NY - 09, Mar - 02.jpg
  St. Patrick's Day - Albany, NY - 09, Mar - 03.jpg
```

When I import my RAW files, I let Lightroom store them automatically in a RAW/year/year-month-day folder, based on the date the photos were taken on. I select all my RAW files, and update their metadata in one fell swoop by setting the Scene attribute to "what" the subject is (here St. Patrick's Day). I also set the Location attributes, i.e. the City, State and Country. The earlier you set this kind of metadata, the better.

When I'm done processing, keywording *and* geotagging my RAW files, I export or publish them to Flickr from Lightroom. My export/publish preset in "File Naming" automatically creates file names that follow the "Scene - City, State - YY, Mon - Counter" pattern, using the fields that I have filled by now (the date is found in the photo itself of course).